# Hibernate database session handling

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I've got an application that uses `sessionFactory` to handle db connection. For example:

```
public List<APN> getList() throws org.hibernate.HibernateException {        
        List<APN> result = (List<APN>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from APN").list();
        return result;
}
```

But if I run this query

```
select * from v$session where username='MY_USER'
```

no rows will be given. Does it mean, hibernate recreates session everytime? Is that ok? Does it mean hibernate creates new jdbc connection per query? I know it's kinda heavy procedure.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.RedirectionServer" />      
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.DeviceType" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.FlowTemplate" />       
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.QoS" />    
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.MonitoringKey" />  
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Rule" />   
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.RuleFlows" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Policy" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.PolicyContent" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.APN" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Location" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.QuotaTemplate" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SGSNNode" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.RuleSCE" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Protocol" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Peer" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.User" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Role" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SessionList" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SessionRule" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SessionLocation" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SubscriptionData" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Subscriber" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SubscriberPolicy" />       
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SubscriberQuota" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.Device" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.RequestCounter" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.pcrf.domain.SessionCounter" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And root-context:

```
    <bean id="dataSourceMain" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <property name="URL">

            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myip:1521:service</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>my_user</value>
        </property>


        <property name="password">
            <value>mypass</value>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props merge="default">
                <prop key="MinLimit">3</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMain" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/db/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>                     
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Comment: Hibernate typically gets connections from a connection pool. How is Hibernate configured?

Comment: I'm not sure why you leave the c3p0 and connection provider class in the hibernate config, since the DataSource is provided by Spring. This makes things confusing. You're using oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource, which does not pool connections. See http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html.

Comment: What class should I use instead?

Comment: I would use HikariCP as a connection pool, delegating to the Oracle DataSource. See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP